# Vue-chart.js : Getting partial data; chart not displaying well

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-chartjs

I want to draw a Line Chart on my `Dashboard.vue`. The data on the `x-axis` and `Y-axis` are coming from my vuex store. I can see data from the store is being accessed when I check with the Vue plugin on my browser.
This is my version of my `LineChart.js` file (where the logic of the chart is located).

```
import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
export default ({
extends: Line,
data() {
    return {
        xAxis: [],
        yAxis: [],
        title: "My activities"
    }
},beforeMount(){
        console.log('beforeMount')

},
computed: {
averageNumbers: function() {
    console.log('computed')
  return this.$store.getters.userData
},
daysItems: function(){
    return this.$store.getters.userDataXAxis
}
},
watch: { // watch changes here

averageNumbers: function(newValue) {
    console.log('watch')
  for (var i=0; i < newValue.length; i++){
    this.yAxis.push(newValue[i].val)

  }
},
daysItems: function(newVal){
    for (var i=0; i < newVal.length; i++){
        this.xAxis.push(newVal[i])    
      }
}
},
methods:{
renderLineChart: function() {
    this.renderChart({
        labels: this.xAxis,
        datasets: [
            { label: this.title, backgroundColor: '#dd4b39', data:      this.yAxis }
        ]
    },
        { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false })

},

},

mounted() {
    console.log('mounted')
        this.renderLineChart();

}
})
```

My Chart just displays as follows (image):
[image: Chart display]

As you can see on the picture, I have two red dots; those are for the two first set of data: `[18 January and 63.5]` & `[21 january and 23.9]` so I am just getting two out of five (total number of data couples for now).
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add a watcher to the vuex computed properties and trigger an update.

```js
this.$data._chart.update()
```

Maybe your chart gets rendered before all your data is there.